# sdk is not pulling down gradle

Tags: gradle, sdk, sdkman

I'm looking to develop an application using gradle, groovy, maven other other products supported by sdkman.  I'm using cygwin on a windows 10 machine.  All seems good and updates most software packages that are needed.  When I get to the point of installing gradle, sdk simply can't download ANY version of gradle.  Is this a bug or am I missing something.  Here's what I'm getting from my cygwin console.

```
Admin@Dale-PC ~
$ sdk install gradle

Downloading: gradle 2.14.1

In progress...

########################################################################     100.0%
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/Admin/.sdkman/archives/gradle-2.14.1.zip or
    /home/Admin/.sdkman/archives/gradle-2.14.1.zip.zip, and cannot find /home/Admin/.sdkman/archives/gradle-2.14.1.zip.ZIP, period.

Stop! The archive was corrupt and has been removed! Please try installing again.

Admin@Dale-PC ~
```

It seems as though sdk thinks it knows where it is however when it goes to pull it down, it doesn't pull down.  Then sdk goes to unpack it and it can't find it.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Btw, I'm not going through a proxy and everything else seems to install just fine.  It is just gradle that has the issue.  Also, why is it trying to pull down an old version of gradle (2.14.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded the [v2.14.1-all](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip) version, renamed the file to be gradle-2.14.1.zip.zip and placed it in the /home/Admin/.sdkman/archives/ directory and then did the install for gradle again. This time it found it and installed it as though it had downloaded the correct version.  It's a solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

`v2.14.1` *is* the newest version of gradle. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes) and [here](https://gradle.org/release-candidate/) (3 is currently in beta-ish)

The filename `.zip.zip` seems erroneous. Possibly a defect in sdkman. Unsure if it was you who reported this on github, but: https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/445